# How can I use the Discord.py 'check' parameter/function used with 'wait_for' in a dynamic way? I want to pass params to the 'check' function

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a trivia/quiz feature for my discord bot, and want to make a 'check' function for the wait_for that I can pass parameters to for what to filter by/against, because currently I am 'hard coding' the quiz questions and functionality. While I'd like to have a JSON file with all the trivia questions that I can randomly select questions from, and pass the answers to the check function, rather than what I have so far:

edit: I have figured it out and left my solution below as an answer.

`

```
import os
import discord
import json
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

def obama_check(message):
    obama = ['Barack Obama', 'barack obama']
    content = message.content.lower()
    return any(t in content for t in obama)

async def quiz(ctx, cache_msg, bot):
    for reaction in cache_msg.reactions:
            async for user in reaction.users():
                users = []
                users.append(user)
    await new_msg.edit(content=":confetti_ball: Game Starting!! :confetti_ball:")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await new_msg.edit(content="Who is the 44th president of the United States?")
    obama = ['Barack Obama', 'barack obama']
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=obama_check)
    if msg:
        await msg.add_reaction('✅')
        await ctx.send(str(msg.author.name) + "wins this one")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await new_msg.edit(content="What is the name of Han Solo’s ship?")
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=hansolo_check)
    if msg:
        await msg.add_reaction('✅')
        await ctx.send(str(msg.author.name) + "wins this one")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

`

some pseudo code of how I want to have it act:

`

```
await new_msg.edit(content=rndm_question.question)
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx, message, rndm_question.answer_list))
        if msg:
            await msg.add_reaction('✅')
            await ctx.send(str(msg.author.name) + "wins this one")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

`

the above function 'quiz' is called in my main file as so:

`

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('TEST')
    await msg.add_reaction('✅')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    users = []
    cache_msg = discord.utils.get(bot.cached_messages, id=msg.id)
    await quiz(ctx, cache_msg, bot)
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own problem by storing my questions+answers in a JSON file, and for the 'check' function I made a global var 'triv' that gets updated in the quiz function with the answer from the json file before calling the wait_for and check function. It works pretty well.

```python
triv = []
async def play_trivia(new_msg, ctx, bot):
    with open("trivia_questions.json", 'r') as f:
        trivia = json.load(f)
    data = trivia['items']
    random.shuffle(data)
    for item in data:
        flag = 0
        for key in item:
            q = item['q']
            a = item['a']
            if flag < 1:
                flag += 1
                await new_msg.edit(content=q)
                global triv
                triv = a
                msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
                if msg:
                    await msg.add_reaction('✅')
                    await ctx.send(str(msg.author.name) + "wins this one")
                await asyncio.sleep(2)
            else:
                flag += 1
                await ctx.send(q)
                triv = a
                msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
                if msg:
                    await msg.add_reaction('✅')
                    await ctx.send(str(msg.author.name) + "wins this one!!")
                await asyncio.sleep(2)

def check(message):
    content = message.content.lower()
    return any(t in content for t in triv)
```